# Preventing Regex skipping the value in the middle

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture some string values in a source code file using the following regex

`[\s\"\']{1}([A-Za-z0-9\_\-]{1,})[\s\"\']{1}`

for variables much like this:

`var components = 'string_1 string_2 string_3';`

But the regexp only captures `string_1` and `string_3` skipping `string_2`

I believe this is caused by the fact that while capturing  `string_1` value, regexp actually detects `'string_1` (notice the `'` and the `space`) and `string_3'` (also notice the `space` and the `'`)  which ends up with `string_2` having nothing on both sides, so it doesn't get captured.

How can I capture all three values.

Please note that regexp needs to capture following scenarios:

```
"string_1"
'string_1'
"string_1 string2"
'string_1 string2'
"string_1 string2 string3"
```

and so forth...

Also it needs not to match

```
$string_1
#string_1$
string_1
//string_1
/*string_1
\string_1
!string_1
```

etc...

I need to capture the values only if they are between single quotes, double quotes, spaces or a mixed pair out of these three.

Comment: Your current pattern is invalid, its parentheses are mis-matched

Comment: FYI `{1}` does absolutely nothing whatsoever, except create noise. Underscore does not need escaping, neither does `-` when first or last in a character class (which yours is). And please correct the syntax error: your character class is malformed - you have a close *round* bracket instead of a closing *square* bracket, if indeed that was your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regex engine is PCRE (PHP) the following regex could be used:

```
(?:\"|\G) *\K\w+(?=.*\")|(?:\'|\G) *\K\w+(?=.*\')
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uXsbyL/3/)

The following operations are performed by the regex engine:

```
(?:          # begin a non-capture group
  \"         # match double-quote
 |           # or
 \G          # continue from where last match ended
)            # end non-capture group
\ *          # match 0+ spaces
\K           # forget everything matched so far
\w+          # match 1+ word chars
(?=          # begin positive lookahead
  .*         # match 0+ chars in same line
  \"         # match double quote
)            # end positive lookahead
|            # or 
(?:\'|\G)    # as above except single rather than double quote
\ *\K\w+     # as above
(?=.*\')     # as above except single rather than double quote
```

Comment: This is awesome. But it matches strings distributed in to multiple lines. See https://regex101.com/r/z68pq5/1 please. Can it be modified not to accept new line or any character other than single quote, double quote and regular space?

Comment: I didn't get the result you mention in your second sentence but I changed permissible characters to word characters (`\w`). Is that OK. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uXsbyL/2/)

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `/(\b\w+?\b)+?/gm`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/W5kD9S/5

Explanation:

- `\b` assert position at a word boundary
- `\w` matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
- `+?` Matches between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

Update:

> I've updated the original question to add a bit more detail and clarification. Unfortunately this matches $string_1 too...

Ok, then you can give this a try: `^(?:'|")(.*)?(?:'|")$`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/W5kD9S/4

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've updated the original question to add a bit more detail and clarification. Unfortunately this matches $string_1 too...

Comment: @monroo No problem. Thanks for the feedback. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I capture all three values.

Use `([^\W]+)` and 1 to many matches will have each of the non spaced items.

Basically one is saying match anything that is **not** in the usable character set `\w` by using `^` (not) `\W` (any non characters) in that set of 1 to many `+`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've updated the original question to add a bit more detail and clarification. Unfortunately this matches $string_1 too...

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different expression for PCRE-based RegEx flavours, which relies on capturing the delimiter, checks in advance whether the same delimiter can be found again after a variable number of permitted characters, and matches permitted words only as long as they follow the opening delimiter.

```regex
/(['"])(?=[\w ]+\1)\K\w+|\G \K\w+/g
```

`\K` is used to remove characters preceding it from returned match strings.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3bEWCP/1).